# Configure server SSH for remote access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, server

I'm a complete begginer in Linux, especially in Linux for servers. I just installer Ubuntu in a server and now I'm trying to configure SSH for remote access.

I installed `openssh-server` and then did `ufw allow 22`.

Now when I do `ssh username@XXX.XXX.X.XXX` in another computer it says that the remote host identification was changed.

I did some research and found [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring) tutorial, but I don't know if it is what I need.

I just want to configure the SSH access to the server.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you use Windows in your desktop PC? Try to use Putty and connect to SSH with only IP address. The SSH server will ask for username during the connection.

Comment: No, I'm using Ubuntu in the desktop PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During SSH request the server presents its id to clien which the client stores along with the host name/IP of the server as known hosts.

When the ID(key) of the server changes(may be due to intallation of ssh server, ip address change, etc), the SSH request fails as the server ID stored in known_hosts is different from the one presented now. This is what has happened.

If you have not made any changes to the server and this happens beware it might indicate a man-in-middle attack where the attacker is trying to snoop you connection to server.

To fix this you need to remove a entry in known_hosts file.

```
ssh-keygen -R <hostname/IP>
```

If you are unsure about your client hostname you can just delete the known_hosts file using

```
rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Well, that was exactly what I was looking for. Ran the commands in the desktop PC and it works as expected. Thanks.